opening reel muted voice via chrome extention
i found the following code in GitHub which is awesome for releasing the block in the videos to pause and play,
const runScript = () => {
    const holder = document.querySelector('div[style="padding-bottom: 177.778%;"]')
    
    if (!holder) {
        console.log('could not find video holder')
    return
    }

    try{
        const video = holder.querySelector('video')
        const nextSib = video.nextSibling

        nextSib.remove()
        video.controls = true

    }catch(e){
        console.log('error from extension', e)
    }
}

// Run every 500ms
setInterval(function() { 
    runScript()
}, 500);

manifest
{
    "name":"Instagram Video Controls",
    "version":"1.0",
    "description":"Add Controls to Instagram videos",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches":["https://www.instagram.com/*"],
            "js":["content.js"],
            "run_at":"document_end"
        }
    ]
}

text
but i try to add the unmuted the video by adding this section
if (holder) {
      const video = holder.querySelector('video');
  
      if (video) {
        if (video.paused) {
          video.play(); // Play the video if it is paused
          video.volume = 1; // Set volume to 100% when playing
           video.muted.value=false; // Ensure the video is unmuted when playing
          console.log('Video playing, volume set to 100% and unmuted.');
        } else {
          video.pause(); // Pause the video if it is playing
          console.log('Video paused.');
          video.muted = false;
        }
      }
    }

but its not unmuting the video when i playthe vieo.
**solved by this code **
ı used background.sj instead of popup and its work fine now
 // Function to set video volume to 100%
  function setVideoVolumeTo100() {
    const holder = document.querySelector('div[style="padding-bottom: 177.778%;"]');
  
    if (holder) {
        const video = holder.querySelector('video');
  
        if (video) {
            video.volume = 1.0; // Set volume to 100%
            video.muted = false; // Unmute the video
            console.log('Volume set to 100% and video unmuted.');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Video holder not found.');
    }
  }
  
  // Open the popup window when the extension icon is clicked
  chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html"),
        type: "popup",
        width: 348,
        height: 654,
        focused: true
    });
  });


any one can help me in this

actualy i solved the problem with backgroun.sj
